# Susy with Google Web Starter Kit

Tags: susy-sass, google-web-starter-kit

Wondering where I went wrong? Trying to get Susy working with Google Web Starter Kit.

1.Cloned [GWSK](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit) into new directory.

2.Ran `yarn` to install dependencies.

3.Installed Susy:

`yarn add susy --dev`

4.Added to gulplfile:

```
/* gulpfile.babel.js */
.pipe($.sass({
  precision: 10,
  includePaths: ['node_modules/susy/sass'] // Added this
```

5.In my styles file:

```
/* main.scss */
@import 'susy';
.content {
  @include container;
}
.col {
  @include span(4);
}
```

6.In the barebones html file:

```
/* basic.html */
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">Lorem.</div>
  <div class="col">Ab.</div>
  <div class="col">Earum?</div>
</div>
```

7.Then `gulp serve` it up.

Yet when `basic.html` loads the divs are not aligned and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to add `of 12`

```
.col {
  @include span(4 of 12);
}
```

That and the fact my css select was `.content` *not* `.container`. Duh.

Comment: The `of n` syntax is there to help you override global settings on-the-fly. If you are using Susy out-of-the-box, the global setting is `4`. So `of 12` does override that global `4`, but you could also change the global setting once – `$susy: ('columns': 12);` – and not have to override in every mixin or function.

Comment: I didn't realize the default is 4. Most often you hear of 12 column grid systems. Is there a reason why Susy was decided to be 4 by defualt?

Comment: We chose it to encourage a mobile-first approach, starting with 4 and adding columns as the screen becomes larger.